# Can short circuiting kill a USB cable?

Tags: usb, android, battery

I have a power strip and four things were connected to it. My air filter, laptop, Samsung Galaxy Tab, and Motorola Droid 4.

For the phone and the tablet, there are actually 2 components to the charging system. There is the actual USB charger and then the USB cable that connects the charger to the device.

Now, someone happened to accidentally spill the water from an iron onto one of the empty slots in the power strip. Everything got short circuited, and afterwards, both my phone and tablet were not charging correctly.

With my phone, I was able to replace the USB cable while using the same charging device, and that seemed to solve my phone issues. The tablet, however, uses a special Samsung USB cable that I don't have an extra of.

In my phone's case, I found it really odd that neither the phone charger or the phone itself broke, but rather the USB cable. Is it possible for the USB cable to break this way? If this is the case, should my first solution for my tablet be to buy a new USB cable for it?

Note: I'm not sure if this matters at all, but I am currently living in China and also using Chinese power strips. Also, I have tried charging my devices on various other power strips, so the power strip isn't the issue.

EDIT: There is an additional reason why I think my Samsung USB cord is broken. When I tried using this USB with different USB chargers, my device still doesn't charge.

Comment: Yes, there is the possibility that the electrical event damaged the cable. In the case of a short, the flow of electricity is changed and takes a newly created low-resistance path, and that path tends to overload the circuitry involved. That probably resulted in a surge which in a power strip can send a lot of extra current through connected equipment. If there were a weak point in the cable, it could have blown part of it out or even melted a section.